# Never meaning to send

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Nights in white satin/
Never reaching the end/
Letters I've written/
**Never meaning to send***

I have problems with understanding the verses "Letters I've written/ Never meaning to send" of the song by The Moody Blues. Does "Never meaning to send" have the same meaning in the context as "never meant to be sent" which would make much more sense to me than the used form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does mean that the letters that are not meant to be posted at the time of writing. But the grammar is correct:

> Letters that I have written, but which I was never meaning to send at the time of writing.

The verb "send" can be active, since the implied subject is "I".

Also, your version doesn't rhyme.